# How to force background-image refresh on live website?

Tags: html, css, caching, background-image

I am trying to change the background image of a live website but the image isn't refreshing.

```
body{ 
 background-image:url('/img/bg.jpg');
}
```

How can i force background image reload?

Comment: your question is not clear enough, it doesn't show your issue . Your code, if the path is correct, is fine . What do you mean by refresh ?

Comment: You need some javascript to replace the url of the background-image.

Comment: The website old background image is still showing, even though i already changed the path.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is probably caching the image rather then trying to request it again.
You can add a query string to the image url - that usually tells the browser to get the image again:

```
body{ 
 background-image:url('/img/bg.jpg?v=2');
}
```

Keep in mind that it will only work the first time you request the image with the query string. The second time it will already be cached.
This strategy is good when you want to force the client to refresh a certain image when you know it changed.

If you want to refresh the image every time (I don't see why you would want to do that) you can generate a random string and append it to the query string. Since you can't generate strings using CSS you can do it with javascript and apply an inline style to the element (in your case the body element).

Comment: Your css file might be cached too. Do you see your updated code on the debugger?